# Proof that $\sin^2(kx)+\cos^2(kx)=1$ with k being any integer

Tags: trigonometry

I know that $\sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$. But how comes $\sin^2(2x)+cos^2(2x)=1$ or $\sin^2(4x)+cos^2(4x)=1$?

Is there any geometrical proof for all these expressions?

Comment: $\sin^2(kx)+\cos^2(kx)=1=1^2$ is Pythagoras' theorem for a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse of length $1$ and angle $kx$.

Comment: From $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ for any $x$ you have (for $x=y$) that $\sin^2y+\cos^2y=1$ for any $y$. Now you can set $y=2x$ or $y=4x$...

Comment: Substitute $x=kt$ into $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$. You get that $\sin^2(kt)+\cos^2(kt)=1$ for all $t$. I mean $\sin^2(kx)+\cos^2(kx)=1$ for all $x$ :-)

Comment: Write $y=4x.$  Then $\sin^2(4x)+cos^2(4x)=1$ just says $\sin^2(y)+cos^2(y)=1$

Comment: $(2\sin x\cos x)^2+(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2=4\sin^2x\cos^2x+\cos^4x-2\cos^2x\sin^2x+\sin^4x=\cos^4x+2\cos^2x\sin^2x+\sin^4x=(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2=1$, but there is a much shorter way.

Comment: There's nothing special about "$x$" in your original formula because it's just a placeholder. In other words, it's true that $$\sin^2(\cdot) + \cos^2(\cdot) = 1$$ as long as the same expression is in both slots where "$(\cdot)$" is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use induction to prove: $\sin^2(nx)+\cos^2(nx)=1$.

Base case: $n=1$: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Assume $\sin^2(nx)+\cos^2(nx)=1$ is true and prove:
$$\sin^2((n+1)x)+\cos^2((n+1)x)=\\
(\sin nx\cos x+\cos nx\sin x)^2+(\cos nx\cos x-\sin nx\sin x)^2=\\
\color{red}{\sin^2nx\cos^2x}+\color{blue}{\cos^2nx\sin^2x}+\color{red}{\cos^2nx\cos^2x}+\color{blue}{\sin^2nx\sin^2x}=\\
\color{red}{(\sin^2nx+\cos^2nx)\cos^2x}+\color{blue}{(\sin^2nx+\cos^2nx)\sin^2x}=\\
\sin^2(nx)+\cos^2(nx)=1.$$

Comment: A rigorous proof. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

It might be worthwhile to point out the underlying logical basis for answering this question. Namely, this is an example of the substitution principle: if you know that an equation is true *for all* $x$ in some set, then by substituting any expression for an element of that set in place of $x$, you get another true equation.

So, $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ is true *for all* real numbers $x$. Therefore, if you substitute any expression for a real number in place of $x$, you get a true equation.

To take an example, if $x$ is a real number then $4x$ is also a real number, because real numbers are closed under multiplication. So, if I substitute $4x$ in place of $x$, I get a true equation: 
$$\sin^2(4x) + \cos^2(4x)=1
$$

Here's one way I try to make this clear when teaching precalculus. If the $x$ is confusing you, replace it by anything else. For example, replace it by FNORK:
$$\sin^2(\text{FNORK}) + \cos^2(\text{FNORK}) = 1
$$
This is a true equation, where we take FNORK as an expression representing any real number. Now feel free to replace FNORK by any other expression representing a real number. For example replace FNORK by $4x$; as explained earlier, $4x$ is a real number if $x$ is a real number.

And, of course, it turns out that you can replace FNORK by any complex number, as hinted in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\cos^2\left(\frac{\sqrt[\pi]{\log(t^2+h)}}{z\csc(\theta)}\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt[\pi]{\log(t^2+h)}}{z\csc(\theta)}\right)=1.$$

Comment: of course only for z not equal to 0 and theta not equal to multiples of pi, and finally t^2>-h.

Comment: @PieterRousseau: you probably mean $t^2\ge1-h$ ?

Comment: I think the identity still holds for complex numbers, does it not?

Comment: @PieterRousseau: and their multiples.

Comment: This is too difficult for me since I haven't studied complex analysis yet. But thank you for such a beautiful hint.

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for a geometrical proof.

Think of a plane and vectors in it transformed by some operator.
In particular consider linear operators in a cartesian coordinate systems.
The coordinate of a vector are transformed by the multiplication by a matrix representing a given linear operator.

In this setting $$\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$$ can be interpreted as how much of the first coordinate of a vector goes into the first coordinate of the transformed vector, and at the same time how much of the second coordinate of a vector goes into the second coordinate of the transformed vector in the case, for instance, that a vector is subjected to two tranformations: a rotation of $\theta$ radians and a subsequent rotation of $-\theta$ (that collectively amouts to no transformation at all).

Indeed, the matrix representation of this global (neutral) transformation is then given by the multiplication of these two matrix:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\phantom{-}\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and then
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta&0\\
0&\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

But we know that this global transformation is a no transformation so it must be that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta&0\\
0&\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
 and so it must be $$\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta = 1$$.

Now let's see what happens to $$\cos^2\theta'+\sin^2\theta'$$ when $\theta' = k\theta$, for whatever real $k$. 
Now if we apply the same geometrical reasoning as before for $\theta'=k\theta$ (two rotations of the same radians but of opposite orientation) we will again have a no transformation and again we will conclude that 
$$\cos^2\theta'+\sin^2\theta' = 1$$ therefore it is also $$\cos^2 k\theta+\sin^2 k\theta = 1$$